# magento 2: how to make validation on same name array input

Tags: magento-2.1, form-validation

I want a validation on same name array dynamic input textbox.Because Magento `data-validate="{required:true}"` is not work on same name so how to validate same name array input validation.I have following html data.How to validate same name in magento 2 ?

```
<input type="text" name="qty[]" class="input-text" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" class="input-text" />
<input type="text" name="qty[]" class="input-text" />
```

Comment: Use custom javascript for this.

Comment: Any url reference for that ?

Answer (score 9):

To validate name array dynamic input text boxes , You need to mention array input field's index like following.

```
<input type="text" name="qty[0]" class="input-text" />
<input type="text" name="qty[1]" class="input-text" />
<input type="text" name="qty[2]" class="input-text" />
```

Comment: Why would this answer get a `-1`? This answer is perfectly fine!

Comment: Life saver. Thank you!

Comment: Perfect answer. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion by @BornCoder is to create new validation for that.

Good solution is to check if one validation method can handle that situation: http://inchoo.net/magento-2/validate-custom-form-in-magento-2/
I prefer to start by use: validate-grouped-qty (because of name of input provided in example but this is only to start search)

Full solution:
There is only some location, where validation rules exist out of box:
SHOP/vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation.js
SHOP/vendor/magento/magento2-base/lib/web/mage/validation/validation.js
And of course , provided by jQuery.
Check it or write custom. No more ways to accomplish task in frontend by using native solution.