# Magento 2 : How to make all address fields required in customer address edit form

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, customer-account, form-validation

I know there are questions here that are about how to make the address required during checkout. This is not that question.

My question is how I can make all address fields required in the customer account page. When the customer is logged in and want to add a new address or edit an existing one. I thought it would be simple: just add the `required-entry`-class. But it turns out that this doesn't work:

```
<?php for ($_i = 1, $_n = $this->helper(\Magento\Customer\Helper\Address::class)->getStreetLines(); $_i < $_n; $_i++): ?>
    <div class="field additional required">
        <label class="label" for="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i+1 ?>">
            <span><?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Street ' . $_i)) ?></span>
        </label>
        <div class="control">
            <input placeholder="<?php echo $block->escapeHtml(__('Street ' . $_i)) ?>"
                   type="text"
                   name="street[]"
                   value="<?php echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr($block->getStreetLine($_i+1)) ?>"
                   title="<?php  echo $this->helper(\Magento\Framework\EscapeHelper::class)->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Street Address %1', $_i + 1)) ?>"
                   id="street_<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_i+1 ?>"
                   class="input-text required-entry">
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endfor; ?>
```

So why doesn't this work? And how can I get it to work?

Answer (score 4):

For those encountering this same issue. The reason behind this is that Magento 2's validator only validates the first input element based by name. In this case, all names are `street[]`, so only the first one is validated. This is also explained in [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/154510/magento-2-how-to-make-validation-on-same-name-array-input).

The solution in this case is to edit the form to make sure the names of the field reflect `street[0]`, `street[1]`, `street[2]`, etc ...

Comment: Thank you Saved my Day(s)